# cordova requirements pass, but the emulation of the hello world app fails to load

Tags: android, cordova

```
$ cordova emulate android

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/carmichael/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/carmichael/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/carmichael/Android/Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 638ms
40 actionable tasks: 40 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
        /home/carmichael/code/liffery/native-app/hello/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/carmichael/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/carmichael/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/carmichael/Android/Sdk
No emulator specified, defaulting to Pixel_3a_API_30_x86
Waiting for emulator to start...
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/carmichael/Android/Sdk]!
```

I'm going around in circles here :D and not getting anywhere fast. I can (i think) build the helloworld app.. but when i run the emulator i get the error above.

Here are my variables set based on the docs and google searches:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Where the android studio is installed to `/home/carmichael/opt/android-studio`.

I am stuck as the requirements from cordova say everything is good:

```
$ cordova requirements   

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29
Gradle: installed /home/carmichael/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/7.1.1/bin/gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. turns out you need to install and play the emulator before running the cordova emulator (at least this is what my 4hour old noob android skills found :D):
https://webconfiguration.wordpress.com/2021/07/07/setting-up-cordova-for-android/